# How were Captain Picard's fish kept safe from the baryon sweep?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, jean-luc-picard

In "Starship Mine," the baryon sweep is employed to purge the *Enterprise* of baryon particles. The sweep is deadly to common forms of organic life (and perhaps uncommon ones), so the ship is evacuated.

Is it stated anywhere how Captain Picard's fish were kept safe from the sweep? The captain has a fish in his ready room and some in his quarters.

Out-of-universe, I doubt the writers cared about the details of baryon-sweep planning to such a fine degree. However, I am interested to hear an in-universe answer, of course.

Comment: Riker snuck in a replacement.

Comment: Probably the same thing that happened to biological specimens from the labs and sickbay - presumably removed to safety during the sweep and put back on board afterwards.

Comment: Out-of-universe, purging the Enterprise of baryons will of course destroy everything, including the Enterprise itself. Protons and neutrons are baryons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the start of the episode we see Doctor Crusher has been in negotiation with the base over the storage and handling of live medical samples.

> **CRUSHER:** *Captain. Arkaria Base does not have the medical storage units I have requested. I have seven living tissue samples that won't survive the baryon sweep anymore than you or I would. **I've tried to reason with them,** but*

Since none of the pets on the ship were in areas where the field was supposed to be diverted, we can reasonably assume that they were on the surface when the sweep took place (along with the crew) and were then beamed or shuttled back afterwards.

Since this is a base that is set aside *specifically for decontamination of ships  in service*, one would assume that they have ample facilities to store any pets and plants.

[image]